# Django: Ordering a QuerySet based on a latest child models field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Lets assume I want to show a list of runners ordered by their latest sprint time.

```
class Runner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Sprint(models.Model):
    runner = models.ForeignKey(Runner)
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is a quick sketch of what I would do in SQL:

```
SELECT runner.id, runner.name, sprint.time
FROM runner
LEFT JOIN sprint ON (sprint.runner_id = runner.id)
WHERE 
  sprint.id = (
    SELECT sprint_inner.id
    FROM sprint as sprint_inner
    WHERE sprint_inner.runner_id = runner.id
    ORDER BY sprint_inner.created DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
  OR sprint.id = NULL
ORDER BY sprint.time ASC
```

The [Django QuerySet documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) states:

> It is permissible to specify a multi-valued field to order the results
>   by (for example, a ManyToManyField field). Normally this won’t be a
>   sensible thing to do and it’s really an advanced usage feature.
>   However, if you know that your queryset’s filtering or available data
>   implies that there will only be one ordering piece of data for each of
>   the main items you are selecting, the ordering may well be exactly
>   what you want to do. Use ordering on multi-valued fields with care and
>   make sure the results are what you expect.

I guess I need to apply some filter here, but I'm not sure what exactly Django expects...

One note because it is not obvious in this example: the Runner table will have several hundred entries, the sprints will also have several hundreds and in some later days probably several thousand entries. The data will be displayed in a paginated view, so sorting in Python is not an option.

The only other possibility I see is writing the SQL myself, but I'd like to avoid this at all cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this via the ORM with only one query, you could grab a list of runners and use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to add their latest sprint id's -- then filter and order those sprints.

```
>>> from django.db.models import Max

# all runners now have a `last_race` attribute,
# which is the `id` of the last sprint they ran
>>> runners = Runner.objects.annotate(last_race=Max("sprint__id"))

# a list of each runner's last sprint ordered by the the sprint's time,
# we use `select_related` to limit lookup queries later on
>>> results = Sprint.objects.filter(id__in=[runner.last_race for runner in runners])
...                         .order_by("time")
...                         .select_related("runner")

# grab the first result
>>> first_result = results[0]

# you can access the runner's details via `.runner`, e.g. `first_result.runner.name`
>>> isinstance(first_result.runner, Runner)
True

# this should only ever execute 2 queries, no matter what you do with the results
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> len(connection.queries)
2
```

This is pretty fast and will still utilize the databases's indices and caching.

A few thousand records isn't all that much, this should work pretty well for those kinds of numbers. If you start running into problems, I suggest you bite the bullet and use raw SQL.

Comment: Doesn't this cause a relatively high memory usage? As far as I can see it pulls at least every runner into the memory and builds a rather large list of their sprint ids. Doing this on every page view with several hundred runners in the DB makes me feel a *little* uncomfortable. This is where caching kicks in, I guess.

Comment: After testing this with 10,000 runners it used less than 10MB (3MB actually…) of RAM. If you think you're going to be needing more than that, you really should be using raw SQL. As always, the best approach to this is to profile first – not speculate. Premature optimisation and all that…

Comment: And, a few hundred records really isn't a lot… certainly not enough to warrant worrying about performance optimisation. A few hundred thousand records is usually where you would start thinking about it, and even then it's usually not much of an issue (toss in an index or two and it's resolved).

Comment: Thanks for testing! I guess this is a reasonable solution for the problem. Sadly, after thinking about this some time I realized this will not solve the problem in my exact use case. First, I need to sort by two ManyToMany fields and second, this will not show Runners that have no sprint at all. I guess I just fall back to writing the SQL myself :/

Answer (score 0):

```
def view_name(request):
    spr = Sprint.objects.values('runner', flat=True).order_by(-created).distinct()
    runners = []
    for s in spr:
        latest_sprint = Sprint.objects.filter(runner=s.runner).order_by(-created)[:1]
        for latest in latest_sprint:
            runners.append({'runner': s.runner, 'time': latest.time})

    return render(request, 'page.html', {
            'runners': runners,
    })


{% for runner in runners %}
    {{runner.runner}} - {{runner.time}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is not getting the latest sprint but ordering the Runner QuerySet by its latest sprint `time` field.

Comment: This does work, yes. Problem is that this moves the ordering of the runners into the application, which causes at least a big memory usage and relatively high CPU usage. Please see the updated question about the table sizes. Another problem with this approach is that it will not show any runners that have no sprint at all. While this can also be solved within the python code, this is a perfect job for the database because it can utilize its indexes and caches. This works for small databases, but our SysAdmin would kill me if I'd do it this way ;)

Comment: hmmm...this is difficult. And we're the same, I'am careful in coding if about my work because of the expectation of my employer. :)